# Is it with grunt-aws possible to set header for individual file types?

Tags: amazon-s3, gruntjs

Is it with [grunt-aws](https://github.com/jpillora/grunt-aws) possible to set headers for individual file types in the same put request?

**Example:**

All .js files -> Cache-Control: max-age=259200

All .html files -> cache-control: public, max-age=0, no-cache

Comment: each file is uploaded (putObject) as an individual, which means 1 request/response cycle. so yes of course it is possible. if you show your grunt-config, maybe someone can help...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would prefer a general example, as my gruntfile does not have something like this now. It's just using the standard grunt-aws for a simple upload - no extra.

Comment: just try it, if you dont get it done, post what you have tried...